# Getting 3D points coordinates of a person as person is walking in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

For a research project, I need to find the coordinates of 3D points on the surface of a person body as the person is walking straight. I know that unity is rendering an object using a mesh based on 3D points coordinates.

I know very little about unity. I wonder if it is possible that I could use unity to create one person character and make him walk and get the 3D points of that person for each 50ms or 1sec, etc and save them to them to a file? So that I could read the points coordinates later using either C# or python and perform my simulation? How easy is that? is there any sample code or example or ready character which I could use in a relatively short time?

If there is any suggestion for any tool or software which I could achieve that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I have to say that the question is too broad for SO, but sure you can. It's not an easy task for a beginner in Unity, by the way. Giving a quick answer, the first (easiest) step is to download a human model with animation from the Asset Store. Than you can import that in Unity, and you can assign some dummy objects as children, in the points you want to monitor (like joints). At regular intervals, you can check for their coordinates and save them. I hope this could be a starting point.

Comment: Are you trying to simulate motion capture using a unity walking animation? Or are you trying to use the unity animation to play back external mocap data?

Comment: Thanks to both of you. The simulation which I am doing is to work out the time and coordinates of points in 3d where a person walking cross a beam of a laser sensor. I can model laser beam in space as a 3d line or 3d cone. As the person crosses the beam the points which the cross would happen can be found using some simulation by writing some code if I know that person is covering which 3d points at each point in time.

Comment: That's actually really easy, it's just a set of `Physics.RayCast`, one per laser.  The Hit data returned by the raycast will tell you where on the person the ray hits.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing to do in my opinion would be using either Kinect or photogrammetry to create your model as Point Cloud which will have vertices on the surface only. This is one of the reasons why i am suggesting Point Cloud because you do not have to find vertices of a mesh on the surface  this way.

Then import it to Unity using [Point Cloud Viewer](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/point-cloud-free-viewer-19811).
At last in Unity you can log all the global positions of the model using `transform.TransformPoint(meshVert)` over time easily.

Comment: Thanks Ali. does the transform you mentioned simulate a walking scenario of point cloud or it is only linear translation in time? I need a walking scenario.

Comment: `transform.TransformPoint(meshVert)` will give you the global position of your vertices. Lets say your human is in the origin and you have a vertex at `(0,0.1,0)` when the human moves to 1 unit in x like this `(1,0,0)` your vertex will be at `(1,0.1,0) globally. You have to log positions of vertices using `TransformPoint` at each interval (50 ms or 1 sec) and it will be different at each time slot.